# Joomla category blog in a module

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I'm trying to take the mainbody display of the home page (featured articles category blog) and display it on some other page as a module.

I'm using `Joomla 2.5.18` and the latest `Gantry framework` with a `Rockettheme Kirigami template`.

I have installed the Sourcerer plugin so I can add PHP code to modules, and now I'm trying to find the PHP code for displaying the **frontpage mainbody** as I think this could be the way.

How do I do this? how can i display the fronted `PHP` code?

So, again, I'm trying to display this on demand: a category blog with a list of featured articles. In a module, so I can use it anywhere.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your mainbody display of the home page must be populated by an article or modules.

- If it is populated by an article, you can copy the desired section the code from that
  article and paste into a Custom HTML module.
- If it is populated by module(s), you can duplicate those modules. If
  you want them in the same position as they are displayed on the home
  page, simply select the other page you would like them to be
  displayed on, from the Menu Assignment tab.